# Конструктор по умолчанию для EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Чтобы обращаться к данным из контроллера нужно объявить экземпляр класса `ApplicationDbContext`. Я хочу это сделать в конструкторе по умолчанию, однако у меня выходит ошибка. Пример я брал отсюда [тыц](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25651342/how-to-add-asp-net-mvc5-identity-authentication-to-existing-database/25651908#25651908)

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {

        public ApplicationDbContext() : base("DefaultConnection")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(@"server=10.28.16.200;Integrated Security=false;User Id=test; Password=pass;database=Zaya");
        }


        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
  base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
```

Вот содержимое `appsettings.json`

```
 "Data": {
    "DefaultConnection": {
      "ConnectionString": "server=10.28.16.200;Integrated Security=false;User Id=test; Password=Radzhab90;database=Zayavki"
    }
```

Вот какая ошибка вылазиит
**Ошибка    CS1729  'IdentityDbContext" не содержит конструктор, который принимает аргументы 1.**

Answer (score 1):

В указанном вами источнике действительно используется базовый конструктор с двумя параметрами, второй параметр вы упустили (throwIfV1Schema).
[image: из 'тыц']

Comment: Оказывается я юзал Identity3) а в примерах Identity2

Comment: Не совсем ясно - проблема решена?

Comment: @ale Пожалуйста, вставьте пример кода в виде текста, а не изображения

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky это не мой код, а всего лишь цитата из ссылки приведенной автором вопроса (и там это тоже изображение), т.е. я просто обратил внимание автора на его собственную информацию